# Lost purchaseToken for In-App Billing Api

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I was integrating Android In-App Billing api. but I lost the purchaseToken as there was a exception thrown somewhere. Now in API 3 I can't re-buy it without consuming the bought product. I can't consume it now as I don't have the purchaseToken? How to retrive it?
Or can I reset the purchase somehow??

Answer (score 0):

You could get it by querying purchases.

Here is an example from Google: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        /*
         * Check for items we own. Notice that for each purchase, we check
         * the developer payload to see if it's correct! See
         * verifyDeveloperPayload().
         */

        // Do we have the premium upgrade?
        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
      ....

     //<- here you can consume your purchase

 }
```